# How to make a custom Laravel policy that overwrites another in certain circumstances?

Tags: laravel, policy, laravel-nova

I am trying to create a Laravel policy (I think this might be best way to do it) that overwrites another policy under certain circumstances. I have two models that have a many to many relationship, `accounts` and `programs`.

I have a policy that prohibits viewing of accounts for users that do not have the account associated with a program that belongs to them. This works fine, but this also presents a problem. This makes it so a user cannot attach an account to a program, because they cannot see it.

What would be the best way to go about solving this? I was thinking about creating a custom policy, as Laravel docs say you can name a policy whatever you want and have it control any action, but I don't quite understand how that would work. I wrote an `attach` method on the `program` and `account` policy, but that doesn't seem to be working.

In summary, I want to restrict the user from seeing the account view page (if it is not associated with a program that belongs to them), but I want to allow them to attach the account to their program.

Comment: Can you please provide the code for policy currently you have